# ANTLR usable with C#

Tags: c#, antlr, grammar, yacc, lex

Over 20 years ago I created a custom compiler for PLC's with yacc/lex  and C/C++ for MS-DOS platform.  Now the same company wants a new version.  The target platform is Windows so my preference would be to use C#.  I've just spent a day looking at ANTLR with C# and haven't so far been able to create a simple parser.  I'm using VS2012 and I'm not finding .Net 4.0 compatible libraries from the latest ANTLR download.  I'm using the Language=CSharp3 and haven't found pre-built .NET libraries.  Attempts to rebuild the libraries from the source give errors when trying to build with VS2012.  I need to decide whether ANTLR and C# is a viable option in the next day or so.  Has anyone used ANTLR with C# to produce a large compiler project?

One of the errors trying to build the CSharp version of the antlr3.Runtime:

Error   1   Cryptographic failure while signing assembly 'c:\ANTLR\runtime\CSharp3\Sources\Antlr3.Runtime\obj\Debug\Antlr3.Runtime.dll' -- 'Error reading key file 'c:\ANTLR\runtime\CSharp3\Sources\Antlr3.Runtime\Key.snk' -- The system cannot find the file specified. '    C:\ANTLR\runtime\CSharp3\Sources\Antlr3.Runtime\CSC Antlr3.Runtime

Answer (score 2):

I beleive you have to create your own key file.

See [How to: Create a Public/Private Key Pair](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6f05ezxy%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Use the SN app from a Visual Studio Command Prompt

```
sn –k c:\ANTLR\runtime\CSharp3\Sources\Antlr3.Runtime\Key.snk
```

Comment: Thanks but that was just the immediate error.  I was trying to determine if the C# target for ANTLR was stable enough for a large project.  After a day or so I discovered that ANTLR doesn't allow left recursion and my existing BNF makes extensive use of left recursion which yacc handles easily.  So I've opted for yacc/lex and managed C++